# How to allow log4j-2.17.2 to download configuarion via HTTP?

Tags: http, log4j2

We have a similar problem to that of the asker of [this question](/questions/71734408/) -- after upgrading from log4j-2.17.1 to 2.17.2, the application, though otherwise working, is not logging *anything*.

Having read the [release notes](https://www.mail-archive.com/announce@apache.org/msg07133.html), I see the following part:

- By default, the only remote protocol allowed for loading configuration files is HTTPS.
  Users can specify a system property to allow others or prevent remote loading entirely.

Indeed, in our case the `log4j2.xml` is downloaded via regular (non-encrypted) HTTP, and that likely explains our problem (as well as that of the other guy). However, try as I might, I cannot find, how to (re)enable the ability to use HTTP -- *which* system property is it, that now controls the capability?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system property you are looking for is called `log4j2.Configuration.allowedProtocols` (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#configurationAllowedProtocols)) and should contained a comma separated list of URL schemes (e.g. "http,https").

You can set it using any available property source (e.g. a `log4j.component.properties` file or a Java system property).